# How to get the 1st character after a pattern using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the first character after the pattern.

i.e.

```
border-top-color
padding-top

/-[a-z]/g
```

selects:

```
border[-t]op[-c]olor
padding[-t]op
```

I want to select:

```
border-[t]op-[c]olor
padding-[t]op
```

How do you just get the first character after a selected pattern?

[Example Here! :)](http://regexr.com/3b0ns)

Comment: What is the language/tool this regex is meant for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a capturing group:

```
"border-top-color".replace(/-([a-z])/g, "-[$1]")
```

Result:

```
"border-[t]op-[c]olor"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the t after `border-`, you usally match with this kind of regex:

```
border-(.)
```

You can then extract the submatch:

```
var characterAfter = str.match(/border-(.)/)[1];
```

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array with the whole match as first element, and the submatches in the following positions.

To get an array of all the caracters following a dash, use

```
var charactersAfter = str.match(/-(.)/g).map(function(s){ return s.slice(1) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use submatching like dystroy said or simply use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to match it:

```
/(?<=-)./
```